# docker - connection refused on android host

Tags: android, docker, firewall

installing and running docker on Android and `sudo docker version` reports that the client and server are available.

Attempting to run any other meaningful command (e.g. `hello-world`, `pull`, `push`, `build`) starts throwing errors.

For instance: `sudo docker build -t img1` results in

```
*ERROR: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:35711->[::1]:53: read: connection refused*
```

- Android does not have `systemd` and `systemctl` and was started manually with `sudo dockerd` without reported errors
- I am not sure of any network restrictions (e.g. firewalls) being implemented within Android that should result in this behavior

Answer (score -1):

I would do the following:

- Make sure Docker is running is running on whatever OS you are running.
- Remove docker from sudo as you will have issues running docker scrips.
  Code to remove or grant `Docker` non sudoe privileges

  `sudo usermod -aG docker username`

I am not sure it is your main issue but it could help.